# Alfresco share authentication

Tags: java, spring, authentication, alfresco, surf

I need to modify the Share authentication mechanism. When a user attempts to login from the share page, I need to add a check that checks for the user's tenant domain with the prefix of the web address. If username's tenant address matches with the prefix of the web address then the user is allowed to log in otherwise the authentication is rejected.

For examples:

user logs in as username@mydomain.com from mydomain.alfresco.com/share

In the above case the user would be allowed to login because ...@mydomain.com matches with the web address prefix mydomain.alfresco.com/share.

I am not sure where to begin and would appreciate any help on accomplishing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would implement it overriding the `loginController` Spring bean. Make a copy of `org.springframework.extensions.surf.mvc.LoginController.java` and add your your custom logic to `handleRequestInternal`. `request.getParameter("username")` and `request.getHeader("Host")` should provide the values for the comparision.

One way to override the default implementation by placing the bean definition in a file `alfresco/web-extension/custom-context.xml` in the classpath.

```
<bean id="loginController" class="CustomLoginController">
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="-1" />
    <property name="useExpiresHeader"><value>true</value></property>
    <property name="useCacheControlHeader"><value>true</value></property>
    <property name="userFactory" ref="user.factory"></property>
    <property name="connectorService" ref="connector.service" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you advice on how to implement the LoginController? This class is never called during the login process.

Comment: Exactly follow the instructions given. You will have to change the body of the method handleRequestInternal in your CustomLoginController class which is based on a copy of org/springframework/extensions/surf/mvc/LoginController.java. Try the spring bean definition above without the custom class and you will see that share fails to start complainig about the missing class.

Comment: I was able to do as you suggested. 
I had put a break point in my LoginController before but the threads didn't suspend, turns out that LoginController from SVN repository is not synced properly with the one installed in Alfresco.